# React event listeners with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [theRoom, setRoom] = useState(null);

  const updateVideoDevice = (e) => {
    console.log("room", theRoom);
  };

  const createRoom = () => {
    console.log("we change the room", theRoom);
    setRoom({
      localparticipants: {}
    });
    console.log("we change the room after", theRoom);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const select = document.getElementById("video-devices");
    select.addEventListener("change", updateVideoDevice);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select id="video-devices">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={createRoom}>change obj</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have this codebase. When I press the change obj button for the **first time** it doesn't set `theRoom` to the object

```
{
          localparticipants: {}
        }
```

But when I press the button for the second time it does, and after that, I try to change the select element's options I got `null` for the console log in the `updateVideoDevice` function.

How do I solve these two issues with React?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [theRoom, setRoom] = useState(null);
```

`setRoom` is asynchronous function, so you will not see the change immediately.

Also, you don't need to add event listener to `select` tag. You can simply use `onChange` method. So remove all with `useEffect` and then change the code as below.

```
<select id="video-devices" onChange={updateVideoDevice}>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to chnage how you call the onclick method so it's look like this:

```
<button onClick={()=>createRoom()}>change obj</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

1. setRoom is asynchronous so your 2 `console.log(theRoom)` can't show the right value while you're still in the function.
2. to handle the select change value, you can use the `onChange` React prop that allows you to catch every value change of a hook
3. I put you 2 `console.log`in a useEffect to allow you to see the changes of the `theRoom` and `selectValue` values

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [theRoom, setRoom] = useState(null);
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(null);

  const createRoom = () => {
    setRoom({
      localparticipants: {}
    });
  };

  // everytime selectValue or theRoom values changed, this trigger this
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectValue);
    console.log(theRoom);
  }, [selectValue, theRoom]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        id="video-devices"
        onChange={(e) => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}
        value={selectValue}
      >
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={createRoom}>change obj</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```